# Карты в три поля?

Tags: java

Можно ли заполнить карту в три поля: то есть, например, два ключа, одно значение? Напишите в коде, пожалуйста!

Comment: В принципе, можно сделать класс, который будет содержать три поля и помещять его объекты в коллекцию! А вот именно как карту сделать на три поля, я вот хочу у вас спросить! Может знаете?

Comment: Используйте две карты: k1->value_object и k2->value_object

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться [**Table**](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table) из библиотеки **Google Guava**